# Application Behavior Differs on Difference Machines And OSes

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm writing a windows (MS) application to get the name of the process of the active window.

On a desktop PC running 32-bit Windows XP Professional the application runs as expected. But on a laptop machine with a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional OS the does not work as expected. For certain processes an invalid handle is returned. I get the same results on an ultrabook running Windows 8.1 64-bit.

The relevant code snippet is as follows:

```
DWORD dwThreadID, dwProcessID;
GUITHREADINFO gti;
HANDLE hProcess;
char szProcessFileName[MAX_PATH] = {0};

gti.cbSize = sizeof(GUITHREADINFO);

GetGUIThreadInfo(0, &gti);

dwThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(gti.hwndActive, &dwProcessID);
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwProcessID);

// Get the name of the process (no error checking for brevity)
GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, szProcessFileName, MAX_PATH);
```

When the application runs in the non-Windows XP OSes, as stated above, for certain processes `OpenProcess` and `GetModuleFileNameEx` fail. `GetModuleFileNameEx` typically fails with ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (error code: 299) or ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (error code: 87) whereas `OpenProcess` fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (error code: 6)

Not sure what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated. I wonder if it has to do with user permissions.

The source code is compiled as a 32-bit application on a 64-bit machine running Windows 7 Pro x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a long read but try... [this](http://winprogger.com/getmodulefilenameex-enumprocessmodulesex-failures-in-wow64/) for starters.

> If you are running on XP or above, the recommended workaround to get at the 64-bit process image path from a 32-bit process, is to use the newer GetProcessImageFileName which gets the path (via  ProcessImageFileName (27) process information class of NtQueryInformationProcess). The wow64 layer does not do much this time because it is just a unicode string. However this function has a downside – the path returned is of the form /Device/HarddiskVolumeX instead of DOS style drive letter based paths.

Note how the one error was trying to tell you that only 32-bits of a 64-bit address was copied into your pointer.  The article describes it better than I can.

Comment: re paths: I noticed that with `GetProcessImageFileName`

Comment: Yes, it's trying to tell you that it only copied half the 64-bit address into that 32-bit storage area.  See the article link "this" above for details.